# Spring 6 configuring a local EJB Stateless Session Bean - are these xml attributes still available?

Tags: spring, jakarta-migration, spring-context

I'm upgrading a web-app to use the latest Spring framework.
The [latest docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/integration/appendix.html#appendix.xsd-schemas-jee-local-slsb-complex) give examples that use the `business-interface` and `lookup-home-on-startup` attributes, but these are no longer present in the [latest *spring-jee.xsd*](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/main/spring-context/src/main/resources/org/springframework/ejb/config/spring-jee.xsd).
They used to be there, but were removed by [this commit](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/commit/d84ca2ba90d27a7c63d7b35a6259b5b9cf341118#diff-75c7143c7ca02e1a87e00116e0f3a0eee2a56f763c6ee5bcb9ebc535c8e0fbf2) *Jakarta EE 9 migration*.

Are the docs correct - can I still use these attributes? If not, what should I replace them with?

Edit: Someone reported this to Spring, [jee:local-slsb no longer works with a business-interface attribute](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/31627), and [they've fixed it](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/commit/695559879e5bd7936cc60fba937889b49c9c2f8e) in [6.1.1](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/releases/tag/v6.1.1)

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, I suspect the documentation is an oversight. The EJB lookup is only for EJB3+ now and if you still have EJB2.x or lower you cannot use those anymore.